# How can I format a post request to http://iswcnet.cisac.org/ to search without having to start from within the site?

Tags: url, search, post, arguments, search-engine

I'm looking to open search results at http://iswcnet.cisac.org/ with the search parameters POSTed from a Greasemonkey form on another site.  Plus, I hate their search interface; it'd be nice to write my own GM wrapper for it, if only I could find how to format the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use URL http://iswcnet.cisac.org/iswcnet/MWI/search.do?

parameters:
firstCriteria=
What to search:
titleFirstCriteria - Title
iswcFirstCriteria - ISWC number
ipNameMwiFirstCriteria - Creator's Name
ipNameNumberFirstCriteria - Creator-Id

firstCriteriaType=
Search type:
E - 'exact'
B - 'begins with'
W - 'contains'

firstCriteriaInput= {the search term}

Example: Search for any work entry by anyone whose name contains "Cobain":
http://iswcnet.cisac.org/iswcnet/MWI/search.do?firstCriteria=ipNameMwiFirstCriteria&firstCriteriaType=B&firstCriteriaInput=Cobain